# splitting file to smaller max n-chars files without cutting any line

Tags: shell, awk

Here is a sample input text file generated with the cal command:

```
$ cal 2743 > sample_text
```

In this example this file have 2180 characters

```
$ wc sample_text
  36  462 2180 sample_text
```

I want to split it into smaller files each one having no more than 700 lines but preserving lines in complete state (no line can be cut)

I can view each such block with following awk code:

```
$ awk '{l=length+l;if(l<=700){print l,$0}else{l=length;print "\nnext block\n",l,$0}}' sample_text
32                             2743
98       January               February               March
164 Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
230                 1  2      1  2  3  4  5  6      1  2  3  4  5  6
296  3  4  5  6  7  8  9   7  8  9 10 11 12 13   7  8  9 10 11 12 13
362 10 11 12 13 14 15 16  14 15 16 17 18 19 20  14 15 16 17 18 19 20
428 17 18 19 20 21 22 23  21 22 23 24 25 26 27  21 22 23 24 25 26 27
494 24 25 26 27 28 29 30  28                    28 29 30 31
560 31
560
626        April                  May                   June
692 Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa

next block
 66              1  2  3                     1         1  2  3  4  5
132  4  5  6  7  8  9 10   2  3  4  5  6  7  8   6  7  8  9 10 11 12
198 11 12 13 14 15 16 17   9 10 11 12 13 14 15  13 14 15 16 17 18 19
264 18 19 20 21 22 23 24  16 17 18 19 20 21 22  20 21 22 23 24 25 26
330 25 26 27 28 29 30     23 24 25 26 27 28 29  27 28 29 30
396                       30 31
396
462         July                 August              September
528 Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
594              1  2  3   1  2  3  4  5  6  7            1  2  3  4
660  4  5  6  7  8  9 10   8  9 10 11 12 13 14   5  6  7  8  9 10 11

next block
 66 11 12 13 14 15 16 17  15 16 17 18 19 20 21  12 13 14 15 16 17 18
132 18 19 20 21 22 23 24  22 23 24 25 26 27 28  19 20 21 22 23 24 25
198 25 26 27 28 29 30 31  29 30 31              26 27 28 29 30
264
264
330       October               November              December
396 Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
462                 1  2      1  2  3  4  5  6            1  2  3  4
528  3  4  5  6  7  8  9   7  8  9 10 11 12 13   5  6  7  8  9 10 11
594 10 11 12 13 14 15 16  14 15 16 17 18 19 20  12 13 14 15 16 17 18
660 17 18 19 20 21 22 23  21 22 23 24 25 26 27  19 20 21 22 23 24 25

next block
 66 24 25 26 27 28 29 30  28 29 30              26 27 28 29 30 31
132 31
```

I have the problem to save each max 700 chars block into separate file - with following command it only produces one file.0, and expected were split files file.0, file.1, file.2 and file.3 for this input example

```
$ awk 'c=0;{l=length+l;if(l<=700){print>"file."c}else{c=c++;l=length;print>"file."c}}' sample_text
$ cksum *
3868619974 2180 file.0
3868619974 2180 sample_text
```

Comment: What happens if a line by itself is bigger than your byte count limit?

Comment: Besides that, you could loop line by line, keeping the count of bytes in the current file, appending it if it fits (i.e., it's length plus the current count is below the limit) or creating a new one if it doesn't.

Comment: When you say `no more than 700 lines` ITYM `no more than 700 characters`. `print>"file."c` is non-POSIX (non-parenthesized expression on right side of input or output redirection) and so will fail in some awks. Likewise in most awks not closing your output files as you go will fail with too many open files once you get past about a dozen.

Comment: and never name a variable `l` as it looks far too much like the number `1` and so obfuscates your code. I was staring at `l=length+l` for a couple of minutes trying to figure out why you were adding `1` to `length()` (e.g.  if it was to account for printing a newline or a blank line or what  the heck you were doing there) before I realized that was the letter `l` not the number `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
BEGIN {
    maxChars = 700
    out = "file.0"
}
{
    numChars = length($0)
    totChars += numChars
    if ( totChars > maxChars ) {
        close(out)
        out = "file." ++cnt
        totChars = numChars
    }
    print > out
}
```